# datatables selected row get undefined value

Tags: javascript, mysql, datatable

i'm pretty new using datatables and amaze with good fiture in datatables for handling a lots of data. i have read the documentation but still don't get the answer, too much example make me confuse which one is fit for my problem.

so, i trying to generated button which can edit value of selected row, but i think to complex for doing a button each row, i made it more simple with hyperlink text generated each button and can edit selected row which taken the ID of selected row.

The problem is when i succeed with generating link each row, the id of row is **undefined**.

on comment code name try 1, my table not showing and keep processing for long time
and comment code name try 2, my table working but when i hit **edit** the value is **undefined**.

here is my code :

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
            var dataTable = $('#empTable').DataTable({
                'processing': true,
                'serverSide': true,
                'serverMethod': 'post',
                'ajax': {
                    'url':'ajaxfile.php',
                    'data': function(data){
                        var gender = $('#searchByGender').val();
                        var name = $('#searchByName').val();
                        data.searchByGender = gender;
                        data.searchByName = name;
                    }
                },
                'columns': [
                    { data: 'id' },
                    { data: 'nama' },
                    { data: 'grade' },
                    { data: 'dept' },
                    { data: 'id' },
                    { data: 'id',
                        render: function(data, type, row, meta)
                        {
                            //try 1 :
                            //var data = table.row( this ).data().id;
                            //return '<a href="../../action/edit_1.php?id='+data+'">edit</a>';
                            
                            //try 2 :
                            //var i = row[0];
                            //return '<a href="../../action/edit_1.php?id='+i+'">edit</a>';
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
```

[undefined ID Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsIX0.png), and
[normally this should be ID ie:2200085 not undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmIh3.png).

any help would be appreciated, sorry if the question just hit little scope but i think out there many people have same problem like me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing one step after columns[].

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var dataTable = $('#empTable').DataTable({
                'processing': true,
                'serverSide': true,
                'serverMethod': 'post',
                'ajax': {
                    'url':'ajaxfile.php',
                    'data': function(data){
                        var gender = $('#searchByGender').val();
                        var name = $('#searchByName').val();
                        data.searchByGender = gender;
                        data.searchByName = name;
                    }
                },
                'columns': [
                    { data: 'id' },
                    { data: 'nama' },
                    { data: 'grade' },
                    { data: 'dept' },
                    { data: 'id' },
                    { data: 'id',
                        render: function(data, type, row, meta)
                        {
                            //try 1 :
                            //var data = table.row( this ).data().id;
                            //return '<a href="../../action/edit_1.php?id='+data+'">edit</a>';
                            
                            //try 2 :
                            //var i = row[0];
                            //return '<a href="../../action/edit_1.php?id='+i+'">edit</a>';
                        }
                    },
                ],
             createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
                    $(row).attr('title','Category ID : '+data[0]);
                    $(row).attr('id',data[0]);
                    $(row).click(function(){
                        alert(this.id+' is clicked');
                });
              }
            });
```

Comment: where should i put the code ? berofe render or inside render ?